# Stackedinline with field id

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create stackedinline at django admin, but i have a problem i have ID which by default is uuid4 but when i specify at stackedinline `fields=('id')` it says:

> FieldError Unknown field(s) (id) specified for POS

Here is my model:

```
class POS(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Ime', max_length=24)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

and then in admin.py

```
class PosInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = POS
    extra = 0
    fields = ('id', 'name',)
```

I even tryed with readonly_fields and put there id but its not displaying anything, i know they are assigned at creation but is it able to display it if its already there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method which returns the `id` of the object.

*models.py*

```
class POS(models.Model):
    # your fields...

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id
```

Now, add this method to `fields` and `readonly_fields` of `PosInLine` class.

*admin.py*

```
class PosInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = POS
    extra = 0
    fields = ('get_id', 'name',)
    readonly_fields = ('get_id',)
```

---

**Note:** The `id` shown for a new object will not be a *correct* `id`. On saving that object, a new *correct* `id` will be assigned to the object.

Answer (score 1):

If your id is also your primary key, you can display that instead:

```
class PosInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = POS
    extra = 0
    fields = ('name',)
    readonly_fields = ('pk',)
```